# Docker build vs Docker run don't behave the same

Tags: docker

I try to build a Docker image with an Archlinux base.
The problem is that I don't have the same result when building the docker image and when doing commands by hand.

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM archlinux/base

RUN pacman -Suy --noconfirm --noprogressbar

$ docker build .
#1 [internal] load .dockerignore
#1 transferring context: 2B done
#1 DONE 0.3s

#2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 transferring dockerfile: 37B done
#2 DONE 0.2s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/archlinux/base:latest
#3 DONE 0.0s

#4 [1/2] FROM docker.io/archlinux/base
#4 CACHED

#5 [2/2] RUN pacman -Suy --noconfirm --noprogressbar
#5 0.692 :: Synchronizing package databases...
#5 1.449 downloading core.db...
#5 3.139 downloading extra.db...
#5 8.344 downloading community.db...
#5 15.38 :: Starting full system upgrade...
#5 15.40 resolving dependencies...
#5 15.55 looking for conflicting packages...
#5 15.56 
#5 15.56 Packages (26) archlinux-keyring-20200820-1  bash-5.0.018-1  ca-certificates-mozilla-3.56-1  curl-7.72.0-2  file-5.39-1  filesystem-2020.08.21-1  gcc-libs-10.2.0-1  glib2-2.64.5-1  glibc-2.32-3  hwids-20200813.1-1  iana-etc-20200812-1  kbd-2.3.0-2  libcap-2.42-1  libgpg-error-1.39-1  libp11-kit-0.23.21-1  libutil-linux-2.36-2  libxcrypt-4.4.17-1  linux-api-headers-5.7-1  p11-kit-0.23.21-1  pacman-mirrorlist-20200801-1  pam-1.4.0-3  pambase-20200721.1-2  sqlite-3.33.0-2  systemd-246.3-1  systemd-libs-246.3-1  util-linux-2.36-2
#5 15.56 
#5 15.56 Total Download Size:    63.83 MiB
#5 15.56 Total Installed Size:  297.78 MiB
#5 15.56 Net Upgrade Size:        7.41 MiB
#5 15.56 
#5 15.56 :: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
#5 15.56 :: Retrieving packages...
#5 15.94 downloading archlinux-keyring-20200820-1-any.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 18.60 downloading linux-api-headers-5.7-1-any.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 21.09 downloading iana-etc-20200812-1-any.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 23.08 downloading filesystem-2020.08.21-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 23.73 downloading glibc-2.32-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 30.46 downloading gcc-libs-10.2.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 38.65 downloading bash-5.0.018-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 42.37 downloading libp11-kit-0.23.21-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 44.24 downloading libcap-2.42-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 44.99 downloading libgpg-error-1.39-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 46.48 downloading systemd-libs-246.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 48.72 downloading p11-kit-0.23.21-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 50.07 downloading ca-certificates-mozilla-3.56-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 52.28 downloading libutil-linux-2.36-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 54.72 downloading curl-7.72.0-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 57.60 downloading glib2-2.64.5-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 60.93 downloading hwids-20200813.1-1-any.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 63.00 downloading pambase-20200721.1-2-any.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 63.38 downloading pam-1.4.0-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 65.26 downloading kbd-2.3.0-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 68.25 downloading pacman-mirrorlist-20200801-1-any.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 68.63 downloading sqlite-3.33.0-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 72.16 downloading libxcrypt-4.4.17-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 73.20 downloading file-5.39-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 75.09 downloading util-linux-2.36-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 79.08 downloading systemd-246.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
#5 85.13 checking keyring...
#5 85.28 checking package integrity...
#5 86.18 loading package files...
#5 86.21 checking for file conflicts...
#5 86.21 checking available disk space...
#5 86.23 error: Partition /etc/resolv.conf is mounted read only
#5 86.23 error: Partition /etc/hosts is mounted read only
#5 86.23 error: not enough free disk space
#5 86.23 error: failed to commit transaction (not enough free disk space)
#5 86.24 Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
#5 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pacman -Suy --noconfirm --noprogressbar]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
------
 > [2/2] RUN pacman -Suy --noconfirm --noprogressbar:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pacman -Suy --noconfirm --noprogressbar]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
```

This fails, I don't understand why.

Same command in a fresh container:

```
$ docker run --rm archlinux/base pacman -Suy --noconfirm --noprogressbar
:: Synchronizing package databases...
downloading core.db...
downloading extra.db...
downloading community.db...
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (26) archlinux-keyring-20200820-1  bash-5.0.018-1  ca-certificates-mozilla-3.56-1  curl-7.72.0-2  file-5.39-1  filesystem-2020.08.21-1  gcc-libs-10.2.0-1  glib2-2.64.5-1  glibc-2.32-3  hwids-20200813.1-1  iana-etc-20200812-1  kbd-2.3.0-2  libcap-2.42-1  libgpg-error-1.39-1  libp11-kit-0.23.21-1  libutil-linux-2.36-2  libxcrypt-4.4.17-1  linux-api-headers-5.7-1  p11-kit-0.23.21-1  pacman-mirrorlist-20200801-1  pam-1.4.0-3  pambase-20200721.1-2  sqlite-3.33.0-2  systemd-246.3-1  systemd-libs-246.3-1  util-linux-2.36-2

Total Download Size:    63.83 MiB
Total Installed Size:  297.78 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:        7.41 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
downloading archlinux-keyring-20200820-1-any.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading linux-api-headers-5.7-1-any.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading iana-etc-20200812-1-any.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading filesystem-2020.08.21-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading glibc-2.32-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading gcc-libs-10.2.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading bash-5.0.018-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading libp11-kit-0.23.21-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading libcap-2.42-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading libgpg-error-1.39-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading systemd-libs-246.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading p11-kit-0.23.21-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading ca-certificates-mozilla-3.56-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading libutil-linux-2.36-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading curl-7.72.0-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading glib2-2.64.5-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading hwids-20200813.1-1-any.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading pambase-20200721.1-2-any.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading pam-1.4.0-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading kbd-2.3.0-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading pacman-mirrorlist-20200801-1-any.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading sqlite-3.33.0-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading libxcrypt-4.4.17-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading file-5.39-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading util-linux-2.36-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
downloading systemd-246.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst...
checking keyring...
checking package integrity...
loading package files...
checking for file conflicts...
checking available disk space...
:: Processing package changes...
upgrading archlinux-keyring...
==> Appending keys from archlinux.gpg...
==> Locally signing trusted keys in keyring...
  -> Locally signing key D8AFDDA07A5B6EDFA7D8CCDAD6D055F927843F1C...
==> ERROR: D8AFDDA07A5B6EDFA7D8CCDAD6D055F927843F1C could not be locally signed.
  -> Locally signing key DDB867B92AA789C165EEFA799B729B06A680C281...
==> ERROR: DDB867B92AA789C165EEFA799B729B06A680C281 could not be locally signed.
  -> Locally signing key 91FFE0700E80619CEB73235CA88E23E377514E00...
==> ERROR: 91FFE0700E80619CEB73235CA88E23E377514E00 could not be locally signed.
  -> Locally signing key 0E8B644079F599DFC1DDC3973348882F6AC6A4C2...
==> ERROR: 0E8B644079F599DFC1DDC3973348882F6AC6A4C2 could not be locally signed.
  -> Locally signing key AB19265E5D7D20687D303246BA1DFB64FFF979E7...
==> ERROR: AB19265E5D7D20687D303246BA1DFB64FFF979E7 could not be locally signed.
upgrading linux-api-headers...
upgrading iana-etc...
upgrading filesystem...
upgrading glibc...
warning: /etc/locale.gen installed as /etc/locale.gen.pacnew
Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
upgrading gcc-libs...
upgrading bash...
upgrading libp11-kit...
upgrading libcap...
upgrading libgpg-error...
upgrading systemd-libs...
upgrading p11-kit...
upgrading ca-certificates-mozilla...
upgrading libutil-linux...
upgrading curl...
upgrading glib2...
upgrading hwids...
upgrading pambase...
upgrading pam...
upgrading kbd...
upgrading pacman-mirrorlist...
warning: /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist installed as /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.pacnew
upgrading sqlite...
installing libxcrypt...
installing file...
upgrading util-linux...
upgrading systemd...
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
( 1/11) Creating system user accounts...
( 2/11) Updating journal message catalog...
( 3/11) Reloading system manager configuration...
  Skipped: Current root is not booted.
( 4/11) Updating udev hardware database...
( 5/11) Applying kernel sysctl settings...
  Skipped: Current root is not booted.
( 6/11) Creating temporary files...
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/journal-nocow.conf:26: Failed to resolve specifier: uninitialized /etc detected, skipping
All rules containing unresolvable specifiers will be skipped.
( 7/11) Reloading device manager configuration...
  Skipped: Device manager is not running.
( 8/11) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
( 9/11) Rebuilding certificate stores...
(10/11) Reloading system bus configuration...
  Skipped: Current root is not booted.
(11/11) Cleaning up package cache...
```

What is the diff between them? And how can I have a Dockerfile that works?

Thanks

PS: this is not a space problem (`df -h` does not show me a "Use%" close to being full)

Comment: It looks like you're building with [buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/). At least on my system, the same Dockerfile builds correctly when not using buildkit.

Comment: It looks like the big problem comes from trying to install systemd.  That tries to control a lot of things (network setup, kernel devices, console ttys, ...) that aren't actually relevant in Docker.  Can you avoid installing that package?

Comment: I don't think systemd is a problem at all. I think it's an interaction between pacman's pre-install checks and the way some files are bind-mounted. It looks like the container configuration under buildkit is different from a non-buildkit build, which seems to avoid this particular issue.

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems related to buildkit, as noticed by larsks. `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/hosts` are mounted read-only when using buildkit. pacman seems to try to update these files, resulting in the error you see.

As a workaround, you can set the [DOCKER_BUILDKIT environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#to-enable-buildkit-builds) from 1 to 0 to disable it. For example:

`DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build .`

Comment: what are your thoughts here on a longer term fix, rather than turning off buildkit forever? I just ran into this exact same problem. What did you do @mykiwi?